# Define a method named encode that accepts a String as input and returns a new String which is the original String encoded using the ROT13 cipher

Tags: java, encode, rot13

For example: String "abc" should return "nop".

I did a System.out.println and it is printing the correct result, however, the JUnit Test case is giving me a red bar. The method move13 just takes the character and moves it 13 spaces left or right.

The method encode is where I am having trouble with.

```
package code;

public class Encoder {

    public char move13(char letter) {
        if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'm') {
            return (char)(letter + 13);
        }
        if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'M') {
            return (char)(letter + 13);
        }
        if (letter >= 'n' && letter <= 'z') {
            return (char)(letter - 13);
        }
        if (letter >= 'N' && letter <= 'Z') {
            return (char)(letter - 13);
        }
        return letter;
    }

    public String encode(String text) {
        String valueOfchar = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char character = text.charAt(i);
            character = move13(character);
            valueOfchar = String.valueOf(character);
            System.out.println(valueOfchar);

        }
        return valueOfchar;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to concatenate values as the return of `encode()`?

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Concatenate each character into one string. However, I do not know how to do that, I tried looking that up as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, hope it helps

```
public static char move13(char letter) {
    if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'm')
        return (char) (letter + 13);
    if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'M')
        return (char) (letter + 13);
    if (letter >= 'n' && letter <= 'z')
        return (char) (letter - 13);
    if (letter >= 'N' && letter <= 'Z')
        return (char) (letter - 13);
    return letter;
}

public static String encode(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char character = text.charAt(i);
        character = move13(character);
        sb.append(character);
        //System.out.println(valueOfchar);

    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

The char are concatenated in a StringBuilder `(sb.append(char))`. After each letter processed in `move13()`, you return the concatenated chars (`sb.toString()`).

Comment: Test passed! Thank you! Can you briefly explain what's going on thats different in your edited version of my code so I can learn it for myself?

Comment: Edited, you only needed to concatenate each letter together.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see the unit test code, but at a guess, your method `encode()` will only ever return a single char, not the whole String.

```
public String encode(String text) {
    String valueOfchar = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    ....
    valueOfchar = String.valueOf(character); // A single char
    ....
}
return valueOfchar;
```

Try:

```
valueOfchar = valueOfchar.concat(String.valueOf(character));
```

Comment: Didn't work either. My expected result is <[nop]> but the result, or the actual is <[]>

Comment: Sorry. Edited my suggestion. It is now correct. But you know, you _could_ look at the API docs for that method and have worked it out for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.